# apply morphTargets to ParticleSystem or PointCloud

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am using Three.js version 65.

I am displaying a set of points @ time t=0 in 3D space using `ParticleSystem`. And also I am having next set of points at time t=1. Now I want to animate it as in `JSONLoader` `morphTarget` animation? Could anybody suggest me the best way to achieve this?

(or)

Can I prefer WebGL shader programming for this? Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that with shaders. You'd e.g. create a custom shader for your particle system with the attributes `vec3 position`, `vec3 nextPosition` and a uniform `float scale` which goes from 0 to 1.
Then you can add some logic to the shader where you calculate the new position like `vec3 pos = position * scale + nextPosition * (1.0 - scale)` (along with the usual billboard / GL_Point code ofc). And when you reached scale 1 you swap `position` with `nextPosition` and fill nextPosition with the relative follower.

Good luck have fun :)

PS: My code mentioned is just for linear interpolation. In your case you might consider other interpolations. Maybe even add another two attribute vectors to indicate the leading and the following point in order to calculate the new position with a bezier curve.

Lastly you'll have to give a thought to performance sooner or later. If you have 10k particles and 1k "states" you might run into performance issues.

Comment: Hi Doidel, Thanks for your reply. Is there any possibility to achieve it in Three.js itself? Since I started Three.js first and WebGL next :( So I am comfortable with Three.js

Comment: yesyes, that answer IS for Three.js ^^ You can use custom shaders with THREE.ParticleSystem. See here for example: http://www.ianww.com/blog/2012/12/16/an-introduction-to-custom-shaders-with-three-dot-js/

Comment: Hi Doidel, Still I am working on it. New challenges also have come. Do you have any experience in selecting faces by drawing rectangle. (Rectangle selection)?

Comment: You'd have to describe what you want to achieve. But rather create a new stackoverflow for that :)

Comment: Hi Doidel, Thanks for your reply. I want to render a 3d model with animation. It is a combination of mesh & particles. I have achieved some basic operations like zoom, pan, rotation, etc., Now I want to hide some faces in the mesh. That is, the user will select the faces by drawing a rectangle in the scene. The faces covered by hte rectangle area should vanish. Hope this would be clear...